# How to solve AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'?

Tags: python, pandas

This code aims to divide a file into multiple according to some conditions.

I print(temp.shape[0]) before the loop, it works. But it show n = temp.shape[0]
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape' in the loop.
I want to know why is that and how to correct it.

```
import pandas as pd

limit = 3
G0 = 7.75e-05
v=0.1           
step_size = 2e-3
splitcounts=200


data1 = pd.read_csv(\
    'C:\\Data Analysis\\Data.txt',\
    sep=',',names=['Time1','Current','Voltage','Distance', 'Time2'])

nrows1 = data1.shape[0]

temp=pd.DataFrame(columns=['Time','Current'])

print(temp.shape[0])#this is right when I run the code

for i,j in zip(range(0, int(nrows1)),range(0, int(splitcounts))):
  if 0<data1.at[i,'Current']<0.000075:
      temp=temp.append(data1.loc[i,0:2])
  else:
      n = temp.shape[0] #but it show 'AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'' 
      if n>5:
             temp.to_csv("C:\\Data Analysis\\Datas/%04d.csv" %j,\
                    sep=',',index=False, header=None)
      else:
          temp = []
```

Comment: You're not giving any data to dataframe? It can be because of that.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the last line of code:

```
temp=[]
```

In this line you are turning `temp` into a list by creating a new empty list. Instead, you should create a empty `DataFrame` using this:

```
temp=pd.DataFrame()
```

**A side note:**

You don't need to make an attribution when using the `append` method. You are doing this:

```
temp=temp.append(data1.loc[i,0:2])
```

Instead, remove the attribution and use only this:

```
temp.append(data1.loc[i,0:2])
```

Usually, the `append` method adds a new entry to the collection without create a new instance.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion! I tried what you said, it does not work. I think the problem is in code after else.

Comment: I'm seeing the error now. In the last line of code, after the last `else` you are doing `temp=[]`. Basically you are turning `temp` in a new list. Instead, you should create a empty `DataFrame` using `temp=pd.DataFrame()`. I'll update the answer with this.

Answer (score 0):

```
temp = pd.DataFrame(temp)
n = temp.shape[0]
```

Add this can change list to array.
The error was solved, but I still cannot split the data to what I need.
Then I add the code as follows:

```
temp = temp.drop(index=temp.index)
```

It works well.
The whole correct code is:

```
for i in range(0, int(nrows1)):
     if 0<data1.at[i,'Current']<0.000075:
         temp = pd.DataFrame(temp)
         temp=temp.append(data1.iloc[i,0:2])
     else:
         #temp = np.array(list, dtype=float)
         temp = pd.DataFrame(temp)
         n = temp.shape[0]
         if n>20:
             #print(temp)
             temp.to_csv("C:/Datas/%04d.csv" %i,\
                     sep=',',index=False, header=None)
             temp = temp.drop(index=temp.index)
         else:
             temp = temp.drop(index=temp.index)
```